# Certain Images with post not appearing when hosted on https

Tags: image, facebook, ssl, facebook-graph-api, facebook-java-sdk

I am creating a post with an image link in it. The images are hosted over https. It works for some servers and not for others.

This works and the image appears correctly with the Post:
https://imageserver.rewardstep.com/imageproxyserver/imgs/WmJy1RGKdmPuuUCBlafI9GvPHRuppV2u1ss9dtLoceH5ZrGKBVjNsxwkZutvj0CW.jpg

This does not. I just get a blank square in place of the image in the post:
https://www.thankyou.com/images/rewards/thumbnail/1112789.jpg

Do you know why this might be happening? Someone told me it is because of the difference in the certs on the two servers - one of them is using EV Cert which might be causing the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was resolved. The problem was a faulty intermediate cert in the chain.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is some bug with sharing HTTPS content. I've tried with verisign certs and godaddy certs and have not successfully been able to share any https content. I'm surprised your one image worked. What kind of cert do you have on the image that did server as HTTPS? Does it work consistently?

I have this bug filed:
http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/post_bug.cgi

Comment: I am not sure what is the difference but I heard someone telling me that the one which is not working is an EV Cert. I guess you can go to the site in the above links and use your browser tools to look at the certs.

I would really appreciate if you can reply here with any update you have on your issue. Thanks!!